# netfilter hook in specific net namespace

Tags: c, linux, namespaces, netfilter

I'm trying use netfilter hook function on particular net namespace, but there isn't any example that demonstrating how to change the parameter &init_net to our own netns created by ip command.

```
static unsigned int verify_hookfunc(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
    char srcIP[16];

    struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
    
    sock_buff = skb;
    if(!sock_buff)
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    
    memset(srcIP, '\0', sizeof(srcIP));
    sprintf(srcIP, "%pI4", &ip_header->saddr);

    if(strcmp(srcIP, "1.2.3.4") == 0){
        printk("see sent modified packet\n");
    }

    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

static int __init init_main(void)
{
    /* Netfilter Hook Function Info */
    nfho.hook     = verify_hookfunc;
    nfho.hooknum  = NF_BR_PRE_ROUTING;
    nfho.pf       = PF_BRIDGE;
    nfho.priority = INT_MIN;
    
    nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, &nfho);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Successfully inserted the hook\n");


    return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_main(void)
{
    struct net *net;
   
    nf_unregister_net_hook(&init_net, &nfho);
    
    printk(KERN_INFO "Successfully unloaded the hook\n");
}


module_init(init_main);
module_exit(cleanup_main);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPLv3");
```

Now, I have 4 net namespace created by ip netns command.

```
/var/run/netns
├── ns1
├── ns2
├── ns3
└── ns4
```

I would like to hook on the particular netns like ns1 by modifying the net parameter in :

```
nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, &nfho);
```

to

```
nf_register_net_hook(net_ns1, &nfho);
```

How could I get the struct net *net_ns1 in netfilter hook funciton?

Thanks for helping!